# How to write a VBA collection to an Excel sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, collections

I have some existing code that I am modifying.  This code creates a collection of rows from preexisting worksheet tables.  It creates a large 2-D collection, with distinct information in each column.  There is a separate class module that declares the data type for each column.

The code writes the 2-D collection to a new sheet by looping through each item in turn.  I have never used a collection before, and would like to write the collection to the sheet in a single pass.  The current code takes quite a long time when the table has lots of records.

Is there a way to convert the entire collection to a 2-D array, or so that I can then write the 2-D array in a single go?  Or is there a way to write the entire collection to the sheet, just like with a 2-D array?  I have tried to search for this and have so far been unsuccessful.  Any general points would be appreciated!

Here is some example code, with comments in bold, to illustrate how the collection is being used.

**Define the Class Module, Named as TableEntry**

```
Public Item1 As String
Public Item2 As String
Public Item3 As String
Public Item4 As Integer
Public Item5 As Integer
```

**Main Routine - Create the Collection, Fill the Collection, Write Collection to Sheet**

```
Sub MainRoutine()

Dim table As Collection
Set table = New Collection

Call FillCollection(File As String, ByRef table As Collection)

Call WriteCollectionToSheet(ByRef table As Collection)
```

**Sub Routine 1 - Fill the Collection**

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(File)

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

Dim R As Range
Set R = ws.Range("A2")

  Dim e As TableEntry
  For i = 1 To 20

    Set e = New TableEntry

    e.Item1 = R.Offset(i + 1, 0).Offset(0, 0)
    e.Item2 = R.Offset(i + 1, 0).Offset(0, 1)
    e.Item3 = R.Offset(i + 1, 0).Offset(0, 2)
    e.Item4 = R.Offset(i + 1, 0).Offset(0, 3)
    e.Item5 = R.Offset(i + 1, 0).Offset(0, 4)

    table.Add e

  Next i

Next ws
```

**Sub Routine 2 - Write Collection to Sheet**

Comment: Thanks rags.  I should have found this myself

Comment: The answer in the link above uses an array instead of a collection.  Is this what I should be doing, or is there a way to transfer a collection to an array, or indeed to write a collection in one pass?

Comment: Actually, if you turn off screen updating and calculations, it will be fast enough, even if you use a loop.

Comment: Thanks @martin, I should remember to do that as standard!

Comment: @psychonomics thanks for updating the question. It makes it a bit clearer now. Can you elaborate on this line `Set e = New TableEntry100613` ? I think that line fails as it stands. Are you dynamically creating Class types? This whole thing looks like you have a collection of your own class that contains 5 items.

Comment: Thank @mehow - that was an error and the Class types are fixed - all with the same simple 2-D structure (different columns of data).  I have been modifying the code for an input source with different structure.

Comment: @mehow - you are correct, the example code has a collection of a custom class that has 5 items.  These items are distinct columns in the original data tables.

Comment: @psychonomics I would recommend using arrays straight from the start if you are rewriting. The use of class could easily be swapped with `Types` unless each class you create receive a unique identifier so you can iterate through Collection Of Collections.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the easiest way to print a *Dictionary* onto Excel spreadsheet is by using `WorksheetFunction.Transpose(`**`Variant`** *type* **`Array`**`)`

*The below code*

- Creates a sample Dictionary with keys and items
- Creates two Arrays *(keys, items)* and fills them with the *elements*
  from the Dictionary *in one go*
- Uses `WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VariantArray)` to print arrays *in
  one go*

```
Option Explicit
```

' Add Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
' >> Tools >> References >> Microsoft Scripting Runtime

```
Sub CollectionToArrayToSpreadSheet()
    Cells.ClearContents
    ' think of this collection as
    '   key     =   cell.row
    '   item    =   cell.value
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    dict.Add Key:=1, Item:="value1"
    dict.Add Key:=2, Item:="value2"
    dict.Add Key:=3, Item:="value3"

    ' THIS WAY
    'Range("A1:A" & UBound(dict.Keys) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    'Range("B1:B" & UBound(dict.Items) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)

    ' OR
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(dict.Keys) + 1, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    Range("B1").Resize(UBound(dict.Items) + 1, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)

End Sub
```

---

## Update:

**In your case...**

If this is what you are trying to do (*note* ***`table`*** *is a Collection*)

```
Range("A1:A" & table.Count) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(table)
```

Unfortunately, the answer is NO.

You can't transpose a collection over to a spreadsheet without iterating through the collection.

What you can do to speed the process up is:

- turn off `Application.ScreenUpdating`
- iterate over the collection and copy the values over to an array,
  then use the `WorksheetFunction.Transpose()` to print
  everything to sheet *in one go* (*use the logic from the first
  part of the answer*)

Follow up:

In your case you can rewrite the `Sub WriteCollectionToSheet(ByRef table As Collection)` like this (*the code looks a bit ugly but the efficiency should be OK*)

```
Sub WriteCollectionToSheet(ByRef table As Collection)

    Dim dict1 As New Dictionary
    Dim dict2 As New Dictionary
    Dim dict3 As New Dictionary
    Dim dict4 As New Dictionary
    Dim dict5 As New Dictionary

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To table.Count
        dict1.Add i, table.Item(i).Item1
        dict2.Add i, table.Item(i).Item2
        dict3.Add i, table.Item(i).Item3
        dict4.Add i, table.Item(i).Item4
        dict5.Add i, table.Item(i).Item5
    Next i

    Range("A1:A" & UBound(dict1.Items) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict1.Items)
    Range("B1:B" & UBound(dict2.Items) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict2.Items)
    Range("C1:C" & UBound(dict3.Items) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict3.Items)
    Range("D1:D" & UBound(dict4.Items) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict4.Items)
    Range("E1:E" & UBound(dict5.Items) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict5.Items)

End Sub
```

More details on VBA Collections iterations and printing to Sheet @ [**vba4all.com**](http://vba4all.com/how-to-write-a-vba-collection-andor-dictionary-scripting-dictionary-to-a-spreadsheet/)

Comment: Thanks @mehow.  Converting to an array and printing in one go sounds good.  Can I still fill the array with the elements in one go if the Collection is specified as `New Collection` rather than `New Dictionary`?

Comment: @psychonomics see, in this case I dont understand how you're having a 2D Collection. How is that implemented and how does it work since the only thing you can get from a Collection is `.Item(index)`. Can you show the code how your Collection is implemented and used? I can then update my answer to match your case 100%

Comment: I have updated my question to include example code.  This should make it clear how the Collection is implemented and used.  If not, please let me know.  And thanks for your help here!

Comment: @psychonomics I have updated my answer upon your update.

Comment: @psychonomics you are welcome. I hope it helped you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35454/discussion-between-psychonomics-and-mehow)

Answer (score 4):

If I want to write a 2D array that I've populated inside the code to a worksheet, I use this code.  It is very efficient, as it only 'talks' to the worksheet once

```
Dim r as Range
Dim var_out as Variant
Set r = Range("OutputValues")  
r.clear
var_out = r.value

'Then use code to appropriately fill the new 2D array var_out, such as your subroutine 1 above

r.value = var_out
```

You start by identifying the range in the workbook you want the array to print to.  In this example, I assumed I named the output range "OutputValues".

The first assignment of r.value to var_out (my array variable I intend to populate) sets the dimensions of the array variable based on the size of the range. (It also reads in any existing values in the range, so if you don't want that, clear the range as I've shown here.)

The second assignment of the array variable to the range writes the values back to the sheet.