# Moving Items from a listbox to a range Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, collections, listbox, vba

I'm starting out with some borrowed code that looks through a single column array (ANALYSIS_S1_V1) with thousands of entries, it de-dupes and sorts them then populates a list box with the result.

Now, I need to list all the items in the collection (in order) on another sheet in my excel spreadsheet.

I'm new to VBA and this forum so hopefully I haven't missed an answer that's already out there. I did find one question that seemed similar but I'm not experienced enough to apply it to the project I'm working on. 
Here is what I've already found:
[How to write a VBA collection to an Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227942/how-to-write-a-vba-collection-to-an-excel-sheet)

I've also searched Microsoft and found what looks like a solution but I can't get it to work in my code (I'm thinking it only works in more sophisticated programming languages even though VB is mentioned):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83h9yskw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates2()
    Dim AllCells As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim NoDupes As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim Swap1, Swap2, Item

'   The items are in a range named ANALYSIS_S1_V1
    Set AllCells = Sheets("Data").Range("ANALYSIS_S1_V1")

'   The next statement ignores the error caused
'   by attempting to add a duplicate key to the collection.
'   The duplicate is not added - which is just what we want!
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In AllCells
            NoDupes.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
'       Note: the 2nd argument (key) for the Add method must be a string
    Next Cell

'   Resume normal error handling
    On Error GoTo 0

'   Sort the collection
    For i = 1 To NoDupes.Count - 1
        For j = i + 1 To NoDupes.Count
            If NoDupes(i) > NoDupes(j) Then
                Swap1 = NoDupes(i)
                Swap2 = NoDupes(j)
                NoDupes.Add Swap1, before:=j
                NoDupes.Add Swap2, before:=i
                NoDupes.Remove i + 1
                NoDupes.Remove j + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    For Each Item In NoDupes
        BasicReportForm1.ReportSubject_Index.AddItem Item
    Next Item

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have all your good stuff in the collection, so to copy the good stuff to a column in another sheet, insert this at the very bottom of your sub:

```
For N = 1 To NoDupes.Count
    Sheets("SheetNew").Range("B" & N).Value = NoDupes.Item(N)
Next N
```