# Writing the values of a VBA collection to a worksheet

Tags: vba, collections

This may sound like an easy question, but I couldn't find a simple way to write the output of a collection ( just a column ) to a worksheet.

Collection gives the correct answers on debug.print and all I want to do that simply put that output on a worksheet, and then clear the output.

This is my main code for collection;

```
Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Visible = True
Dim LastRowXL_1, LastRowXL_2, LastRowXL_3 As Long
Dim uniques As Collection
Dim Source_XL As Range

LastRowXL_1 = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Cells(Rows.Count, 40).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowXL_2 = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Cells(Rows.Count, 41).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowXL_2_Q = LastRowXL_2 + 1
LastRowXL_3 = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Cells(Rows.Count, 42).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowXL_3_Q = LastRowXL_3 + 1
LastRowXL_4_Q = LastRowXL_3_Q + LastRowXL_1 + 1

XL_Main = WorksheetFunction.Max(LastRowXL_1, LastRowXL_2, LastRowXL_3)

Set Source_XL = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AN2:AP" & XL_Main & "")
Set uniques = GetUniqueValues(Source_XL.Value)
```

Comment: The link below might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227942/how-to-write-a-vba-collection-to-an-excel-sheet

Comment: I doubt that you can do a `Debug.print` on a collection - this throws an error (*450 - Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment*). You have to loop over the items of the collection to print it or to write it into a sheet.

Comment: Can you post your code which successfully debug.prints the values? As @funthomas said, you must be iterating over the values

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, just by simply putting a For array after the collection.
I Put these codes after the collection and voila, it works right now;

```
Dim it_XL

Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AN1:AP1100").Select
Selection.ClearContents

it_XLQ = 1
For Each it_XL In uniques
If it_XLQ = 1 Then it_XLQ_M = 100 Else it_XLQ_M = it_XLQ - 1
Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AP" & it_XLQ & "") = it_XL
If Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AP" & it_XLQ & "") = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AP" & it_XLQ_M & "") Then
Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AP" & it_XLQ & "").Delete
GoTo Son2
Else: GoTo Son3
End If
Son3:
it_XLQ = it_XLQ + 1
Next

Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AP1:AP20").Copy
Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AQ1:AQ20").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Son2:

LastRow_END = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Cells(Rows.Count, 43).End(xlUp).Row
```